# How can I leave a permanent notification in kotlin?

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin

I have tried setting a FLAG_NO_CLEAR flag, but when I close the recent applications application, the notification closes.
I also tried "ongoing" but the same thing keeps happening.
Someone who knows how to fix it?

this my code in main activity:

```
public fun createNotificationChannel(contextLocal : Context,avalaible:Int,spent:Int) {

        val prefs = contextLocal.getSharedPreferences("FlutterSharedPreferences" , Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        var velo = Math.round(Math.round(prefs.getFloat("velocityLocal", 0.toFloat()) * 100.0) / 100.0 * 10.0) / 10.0
        modeL = prefs.getString("modeL", "")!!
        var distance = Math.round(Math.round((velo * (avalaible.toDouble() / 60.toDouble())) * 100.0) / 100.0 * 10.0) / 10.0 /* CONVERTER DECIMAL 2 DIGITS */

        notificationManager = contextLocal.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        /* NOTIFICATIONS */
        val snoozeIntent = Intent(contextLocal, ReceiverRepo::class.java).apply {
            action = "NOTIFICATION_TAPED"
        }
        val snoozePendingIntent: PendingIntent = 
            PendingIntent.getBroadcast(contextLocal, 0, snoozeIntent, 0)
        // var action : Notification.Action = Notification.Action.Builder(R.drawable.app_icon, "Stop", snoozePendingIntent).build();

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            notificationChannel = NotificationChannel(channelId,description,NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH)
            notificationChannel.enableLights(true)
            notificationChannel.enableVibration(false)
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel)

            builder = Notification.Builder(contextLocal,channelId)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_icon)
                .setContentTitle("Approximately : " + distance.toString() + " km")
                .setContentText(modeL + " " + "- " + velo+ " km/h " + "in " + avalaible.toString() + " min")
                .setSubText("avalaible time : " + (avalaible - spent).toString() + " min")
                .setContentIntent(snoozePendingIntent)

                /* .setOngoing(true) */

        }
        notificationManager.notify(1234,builder.build())
        
    }
```

my BroadCastReceiver:

```
class ReceiverRepo : BroadcastReceiver() {
override fun onReceive(contextLocal: Context, intent: Intent){
    

    val prefs = contextLocal.getSharedPreferences("FlutterSharedPreferences" , Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    val avalaible = prefs.getLong("flutter.avalaibleTime" , 0)
    val spent = prefs.getLong("flutter.timeSpent" , 0)
    val switch = prefs.getBoolean("flutter.switched" , false)
    val state = prefs.getBoolean("flutter.state", false)

    if(avalaible == spent){
        with(prefs.edit()) { 
            /* MODIFY VARS SHARED*/
            putBoolean("flutter.state", false)
            apply()
        }

        // close notification
        var ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE
        var nMgr = contextLocal.getSystemService(ns) as NotificationManager
        nMgr.cancel(1234)
    }
    if(intent.action.equals("NOTIFICATION_TAPED")){
        Log.d("NOTIFICATION", "LE DI CLICK AL BOTON DE LA NOTIFICACION")

        // open the application by clicking
        var packageManager = contextLocal.getPackageManager();
        
        // create the attempt, taking into account the package name
        val intent1: Intent = 
        packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.example.myProject")!!
        contextLocal.startActivity(intent1)
        
    }
    if(intent.action.equals("NOTIFICATION_TAPED_FULL")){
        
        
    }
    if(intent.action.equals("INTENT_ALARM") && switch && avalaible > spent){

        with(prefs.edit()) { 
            /* MODIFY VARS SHARED*/
            putLong("flutter.timeSpent", spent + 3)
            putInt("timeSpentLocal", spent.toInt() + 3)
            putLong("flutter.avalaibleTime", avalaible)
            putBoolean("flutter.state", true)
            apply()
        }

        
        /* CONFIGURE WORKER */
        try{
            TestActivity.workerInitialize(contextLocal)
            
            Log.d("VELOCITY IN BROADCAST" , TestActivity.velocity.toString())
            /* setAlarm(contextLocal, 180000) */
        }catch(e : Exception){
            Log.d("prueba" , e.toString())
            TestActivity.createNotificationError(contextLocal)
        
        /* CONFIGURE NEXT ALARM */
        }
    }
}

fun setAlarm(context : Context , milis: Long) {
    lateinit var contextLocal : Context
    contextLocal = context
    lateinit var alarmManager : AlarmManager

    /* Log.d("prueba" , "estoy en el setAlarmmmm") */
    alarmManager = contextLocal.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
    var intent = Intent(contextLocal,ReceiverRepo::class.java)
    intent.apply {action = "INTENT_ALARM" }
    var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(contextLocal, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
    alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + milis, pendingIntent)
 }
```

}

The previous code, puts an alarm if some conditions are met, what I want is to put a fixed notification, which takes the variables, and is removed when it has reached 0

Comment: Welcome!  Do you have any example code you could post so we can see what you have already done?